Run a separate cpp file in Clion
I am a beginner in C++and I use Clion software to write my code. However, I have found that I cannot run multiple files in one project. How can I solve this problem? Thank you very much!
I searched on the internet and tried to install a plugin called C/C++Single File Execution. I right-click on 'Add executable for single c/cpp file' in my file, but a prompt popped up saying 'add.exe executable for this source already exists'
At the same time, I also modified the CMakeLists.txt file. After I just downloaded Clion, I changed it to this:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.29)
project(untitled)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)

add_executable(untitled main.cpp)

add_executable(2 2/2.cpp)

file (GLOB_RECURSE files *.cpp)

foreach (file ${files})
    string(REGEX REPLACE ".+/(.+)\\..*" "\\1" exe ${file})
    add_executable (${exe} ${file}
            2/1.cpp
            2/2.cpp)
    message (\ \ \ \ --\ src/${exe}.cpp\ will\ be\ compiled\ to\ bin/${exe})
endforeach ()

add_executable(2 2/2.cpp)

After I installed this plugin and ran it for the first time, the prompt "add.exe table for this source already exists" appeared. Then I changed it to this:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.29)
project(untitled)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)

add_executable(untitled main.cpp)

add_executable(2 2/2.cpp)

